# Perform a pipelines aggregation over the full set of potential buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

When using the `_search` API of Elasticsearch, if you set size to 10, and perform an `avg` metric aggregation, the average will be of all values across the dataset matching the query, not just the average of the 10 items returned in the `hits` array.

On the other hand, if you perform a `terms` aggregation and set the `size` of the `terms` aggregation to be 10, then performing an `avg_buckets` aggregation on those `terms` buckets will calculate an average over only those 10 buckets - not all potential buckets.

How can I calculate the an average of some field across all potential buckets, but still only have 10 items in the `buckets` array?

---

To make my question more concrete, consider this example: Suppose that I am a hat maker. Multiple stores carry my hats. I have an Elasticsearch index `hat-sales` which has one document for each time one of my hats is sold. Included in this document is price and that store at which the hat was sold.

Here are two examples of the documents I tested this on:

```
{
  "type": "top",
  "color": "black",
  "price": 19,
  "store": "Macy's"
}
{
  "type": "fez",
  "color": "red",
  "price": 94,
  "store": "Walmart"
}
```

If I want to find the average price of all the hats I have sold, I can run this:

```
GET hat-sales/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "average_hat_price": {
      "avg": {
        "field": "price"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And `average_hat_price` will be the same whether `size` is set to 0, 3, or whatever.

OK, now I want to find the top 3 stores which have sold the most number of hats. I also want to compare them with the average number of hats sold at a store. So I *want* to do something like this:

```
GET hat-sales/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_store": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "store.keyword",
        "size": 3
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sales_count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "_id"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "avg sales at a store": {
      "avg_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "by_store>sales_count"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which yields a response of

```
"aggregations" : {
    "by_store" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 8,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Macy's",
          "doc_count" : 6,
          "sales_count" : {
            "value" : 6
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Walmart",
          "doc_count" : 5,
          "sales_count" : {
            "value" : 5
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Dillard's",
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "sales_count" : {
            "value" : 3
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "avg sales at a store" : {
      "value" : 4.666666666666667
    }
  }
```

The problem is that `avg sales at a store` is calculated over only Macy's, Walmart, and Dillard's. If I want to find the average over all store, I have to set `aggs.by_store.terms.size` to 65536. (65536 because that is the default maximum number of terms buckets and I do not know *a priori* how many buckets there may be.) This gives a result of:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "by_store" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Macy's",
          "doc_count" : 6,
          "sales_count" : {
            "value" : 6
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Walmart",
          "doc_count" : 5,
          "sales_count" : {
            "value" : 5
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Dillard's",
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "sales_count" : {
            "value" : 3
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Target",
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "sales_count" : {
            "value" : 3
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Harrod's",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "sales_count" : {
            "value" : 2
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Men's Warehouse",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "sales_count" : {
            "value" : 2
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Sears",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "sales_count" : {
            "value" : 1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "avg sales at a store" : {
      "value" : 3.142857142857143
    }
  }
```

So the average number of hats sold per store is 3.1, not 4.6. But in the `buckets` array I want to see only the top 3 stores.

Comment: can you share the queries you are running?

Comment: Mr. Walkom, I have shared queries. I have tried to make the example as simple as possible while still showing my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you are aiming at without a pipeline aggregation. It sort of cheats the aggregation framework, but, it works.

**Here is the data setup:**

```
PUT hat_sales
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "storename": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST hat_sales/_bulk?refresh=true
{"index": {}}
{"storename": "foo"}
{"index": {}}
{"storename": "foo"}
{"index": {}}
{"storename": "bar"}
{"index": {}}
{"storename": "baz"}
{"index": {}}
{"storename": "baz"}
{"index": {}}
{"storename": "baz"}
```

Here is the tricky query:

```
GET hat_sales/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "stores": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "storename",
        "size": 2
      }
    },
    "average_sales_count": {
      "avg_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "stores>_count"
      }
    },
    "cheat": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "all": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "storename"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "storename"
          }
        },
        "unique_count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "storename"
          }
        },
        "total_average": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "total": "count",
              "unique": "unique_count"
            },
            "script": "params.total / params.unique"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is a *small* abuse of the aggs framework. But, the idea is that you effectively want `num_stores/num_docs`. I restricted the `num_docs` to only docs that actually have the `storefield` name.

I got around some validations by using the [filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html) agg which is technically a multi-bucket agg (though I only care about one bucket).

Then I get the unique count through cardinality (num stores) and the total count (value_count) and use a `bucket_script` to finish it off.

All in all, here is the *slightly* mangled result :D

```json
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 6,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "cheat" : {
      "buckets" : {
        "all" : {
          "doc_count" : 6,
          "count" : {
            "value" : 6
          },
          "unique_count" : {
            "value" : 3
          },
          "total_average" : {
            "value" : 2.0
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "stores" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 1,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "baz",
          "doc_count" : 3
        },
        {
          "key" : "foo",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    },
    "average_sales_count" : {
      "value" : 2.5
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `cheat.buckets.all.total_average` is `2.0` (the true average) while the old way (pipeline average) is the non-global average of `2.5`

Comment: What if we want to find the *median* (i.e. 50th percentile) number of hats sold over all stores. In the case of averaging, we can cheat and calculate `num_stores / num_docs`, but in general, how can we calculate some value for all buckets (the number of hats sold) and perform a metric aggregation on that value (average, median, etc), but then only actually return a few buckets?

Comment: Here is an option with percentiles: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-percentiles-bucket-aggregation.html. You could use the same trick here. As for "calculate over every bucket but only return a couple" If you want to really do that for all cases, you need to use [transforms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transforms.html) to first pivot your data (buckets become docs) and then aggregate again.